# Sql statement to combine three tables with char column criteria

Tags: sql

I have to fix a very poorly designed database.

**The problem:**

One Job Advertisment has one jobtitle, but many qualifying degrees.

(e.g., JobTitle:Analyst, Qualifications: Accounting Degree, or Finance Degree or Business Degree)

**The tables:**

TableName: *UniqueJobName* Columns: *jobName*(char) *uniqueJobUid*(bigint)

TableName: *UniqueDegree* Columns: *degreeName*(char) *degreeUid*(bigint)

TableName: *Jobs* Columns: *jobName*(char) *jobUid*(bigint),*uniqueJobUid*(bigint)

TableName: *Job_Degree*: *jobUid*(char) *degreeName*(char)

**Relations**

onetomany UniqueJobName.uniqueJobUid -> Jobs.uniqueJobUid

onetomany Jobs.jobUid-> Job_Degree.jobUid

There is NO relation between Jobs  and UniqueDegree.

**Technical Requirement**

Rather than creating a column in Job_Degree for degreeUid, I want to create a new table: *UniqueJob_UniqueDegree_Job* (There are reasons for this that I won't explain here)

*UniqueJob_UniqueDegree_Job* will have three columns:

- uniqueJobUid
- jobId
- degreeId

The trouble is that the Job table is already very big, 500,000 rows (and the Job_Degree table even bigger)

**QUESTION:**
What is the most efficient SQL statement for creating the UniqueJob_UniqueDegree_Job table given that part of the statement will be comparing the char column of UniqueDegree.degreeName and Job_Degree.degreeName?

Any hints would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select j.jobname, j.jobuid, ud.degreeid
 into UniqueJob_UniqueDegree_Job
 from jobs j 
 join job_degree jd on j.jobuid = jd.jobuid 
 join uniquedegree ud on ud.jobname = jd.jobname
```

Having a hard time with getting uppercase letters etc because I use a worthless cellphone.

This should however do it. Note in order to do select Into... From the table cannot be created already (you can use convert or cast on each attribute in the select statement to get the data types correct with certainty.

If the table already exist then alter the query into

```
insert Into .. 
select ...
from ....
```

500k rows is rather small as well. This shouldn't take more than a couple of seconds I'd estimate.